# Problems drawing curves on ellipsoid

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, draw

I'm trying to draw an ellipsoid but I have trouble matching this dashed curve  with the limit of the shading in the picture, as you can see in the image ... what am I forgetting?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}


\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{0}

%define polar coordinates for some vector
%TODO: look into using 3d spherical coordinate system
\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
thick, font = \scriptsize, >={[scale =1]Stealth},
fip/.style ={circle, fill = fcolor, draw = fcolor, inner sep = 1pt}
]


\def\OP{.4} % Deines the Opacity    
\def\Fi{70} % Deines the filling percentage in contrast to the drawing
\def \yaxis{2}
%start tikz picture, and use the tdplot_main_coords style to implement the    display 
%coordinate transformation provided by 3dplot
\begin{scope}[scale=2.5,tdplot_main_coords,yshift=.7cm,xshift=-1cm]
%draw the main coordinate system axes
 \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=south east]{$x$};
 \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
 \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

 \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}

%draw some dashed arcs, demonstrating direct arc drawing ... 
%the problem is here
 \draw[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords] (.75\radius,0,0) arc (0:75:\radius);

 \draw[dashed] (\radius,0,0) arc (0:360:\radius);
 \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.2] (1cm,0) arc (0:-180:1cm and 7.5mm) arc (180:0:1cm and .75cm);
% (-z x y)
 \draw (0, 1, 0) node [circle, fill=blue, inner sep=.02cm] () {};
 \draw (0, 0, 1) node [circle, fill=green, inner sep=.02cm] () {};
 \draw (-1, 0, 0) node [circle, fill=red, inner sep=.02cm] () {};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\tdplotsetmaincoords` isn't the problem ... indeed, the problem is marked in the code with `%the problem is here` the problem is I can't match the dashed curve with the limit of the shading in the picture. Because that I put `\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{0}` so that the problem is seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question but you can draw the arc as a plot.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}


\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}

%define polar coordinates for some vector
%TODO: look into using 3d spherical coordinate system
\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
thick, font = \scriptsize, >={[scale =1]Stealth},
fip/.style ={circle, fill = fcolor, draw = fcolor, inner sep = 1pt}
]


\def\OP{.4} % Deines the Opacity    
\def\Fi{70} % Deines the filling percentage in contrast to the drawing
\def \yaxis{2}
%start tikz picture, and use the tdplot_main_coords style to implement the    display 
%coordinate transformation provided by 3dplot
\begin{scope}[scale=2.5,tdplot_main_coords,yshift=.7cm,xshift=-1cm]
%draw the main coordinate system axes
 \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=south east]{$x$};
 \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
 \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}

%draw some dashed arcs, demonstrating direct arc drawing ... 
%the problem is here
 \draw[dashed,domain=0:90] 
 plot[variable=\x] ({\radius*cos(\x)*cos(\phivec)},
 {0.75*\radius*cos(\x)*sin(\phivec)},{0.75*\radius*sin(\x)});


 \draw[dashed] (\radius,0,0) arc (0:360:\radius);
%  plot[variable=\x,domain=-180:180] ({\radius*cos(0)*cos(\x)},
%  {0.75*\radius*cos(0)*sin(\x)},{0.75*\radius*sin(0)});
 \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.2] (1cm,0) arc (0:-180:1cm and 7.5mm) arc (180:0:1cm and .75cm);
% (-z x y)
 \draw (0, 1, 0) node [circle, fill=blue, inner sep=.02cm] () {};
 \draw (0, 0, 1) node [circle, fill=green, inner sep=.02cm] () {};
 \draw (-1, 0, 0) node [circle, fill=red, inner sep=.02cm] () {};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with `\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{0}`

[image]

Comment: Yes, you understand my question. Thank you.